# how to get state value according props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose i am geeting one from question props so i want to access state according one

```js
class Question extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            questions:{
                one:{
                    question:"What is html full fomr",
                    options:{
                        a:"hyper text markup language",
                        b:"hyper text model language"
                    },
                    answer:"hyper text markup language",
                    submit:"not",
                    submited_answer:""
                }
            },
            show_question:this.props.question
        }
    }
    render(){
        let question_id=this.state.show_question
        let object=this.state.questions
        console.log(object.question_id.question)
        return "hello world"
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Question question='one' />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

It's giving me an error Cannot read property 'question' of undefined

Comment: either use componetDidupdate life cycle or direct pass props to render. It's not good practice to use props in constructor method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your props.question is a string, you cannot access your state.questions property by the dot notation.
`console.log(object.question_id.question)`

But you can by using the object bracket notation, like this:
`console.log(object[question_id].question)`

Here is a working example with your code:

```js
class Question extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            questions:{
                one:{
                    question:"What is html full fomr",
                    options:{
                        a:"hyper text markup language",
                        b:"hyper text model language"
                    },
                    answer:"hyper text markup language",
                    submit:"not",
                    submited_answer:""
                }
            },
            show_question:this.props.question
        }
    }
    render(){
        let question_id=this.state.show_question
        let object=this.state.questions
        console.log(object[question_id].question)
        return "hello world"
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Question question='one' />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to access the question , where your question id is passed in props.

```
show_question:this.props.question
```

So, now you need to

```
render(){
            let question_id=this.state.show_question;
            let object=this.state.questions;
            console.log(object['question_id'].question);
            // this.state.questions['question_id'].question; //directly. 
            return "hello world";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `object[question_id].question`

```
render() {
      let question_id=this.state.show_question
      let object=this.state.questions

      console.log(object[question_id].question)

      return "hello world"
}
```